# how to draw a 2d Tree

Tags: java, tree

Can anyone help me figure out how to make a 2d graphic tree? This is all I have so far. I have no clue what I am doing:/ Can someone teach me how to..please? & thank you!

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;

public class Tree extends Canvas {

    public Tree() {

        350 200 100 350    
        249 0 249           
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a picture of something like you want?

Comment: I added a link. @MadProgrammer

Comment: That's a really large requirement, made less easy by the need to get involved in some of the more complex concepts of the API

Comment: API? @MadProgrammer    we are allowed to do any tree if that's to complex for my level I can do something more simple.

Comment: This is too broad to be in the scope of an SO question. You should google for some java 2d graphics tutorials..

Comment: okay will do. Any recommendations? @bhspencer

Comment: [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Answer (score 1):

Start by having a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/).  You might also like to have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about painting in Swing and AWT

Simple tree...

[image: Tree]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Forest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Forest();
    }

    public Forest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            g2d.setColor(new Color(139, 69, 19));
            g2d.fillRect((width / 2) - 20, height / 2, 40, height / 2);

            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            int radius = 60;
            g2d.fillOval((width / 2) - radius, (height / 2) - (radius), radius * 2, radius * 2);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }


}
```

Complex Tree...

[image: Tree]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Forest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Forest();
    }

    public Forest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            g2d.setColor(new Color(139, 69, 19));
            g2d.fillRect((width / 2) - 20, height / 2, 40, height / 2);

            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            int radius = 60;
            g2d.fillOval((width / 2) - radius, (height / 2) - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2);
            g2d.fillOval((width / 2) - radius, (height / 2) - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
            g2d.fillOval((width / 2) - (radius * 2), (height / 2) - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
            g2d.fillOval((width / 2), (height / 2) - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thats a nice tree you have drawn there :)

Comment: @bhspencer It's my "South Park" phase ;)

Comment: How did you know what numbers to use to make the shape? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @JohnBull Practice and a little bit of guess work.  If I really wanted to spend more time on it, I would make the `radius` value a factor of the width and height so the tree could grow/shrink based on the available size of the container